# Syntax error and FlatAlertBox is not a member of 'FormSkin1.FormSkin'

Tags: vb.net

I've fixed most of the errors. I'm only getting syntax error now. It shows that ByVal is causing syntax error?

Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
    Dim hostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(FlatTextBox1.Text)
    Dim ip As IPAddress() = hostname.AddressList
    FlatAlertBox1.Text = ip(0).ToString()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I fixed most of them, but i'm still getting the syntax error. It shows syntax error and when i click it marks ByVal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function signature is broken.  Take a look (re-spaced to line up):

```
Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
                                                             ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
```

Looks like a copy/paste error.  Once the function signature is closed, you can't continue with it.